# Detect progress of a download from HTML download attribute

Tags: javascript

When using the [download attribute on a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), is there a way to measure the progress of the download? Whether it has started or finished etc.
At the moment in our UI we show a message saying "Download starting soon" after the user has clicked. Ideally we would hide this message once the download has actually started.

Comment: you could listen to `click` event for the link and when it fires hide the message

Comment: It is not available for security porposes. Possible only with extension api.

Comment: You may consider, if feasible, downloading within the script, with `fetch`, like described [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-download-a-file-using-javascript-fec4685c0a22)

Comment: This can't be done using the `download` attribute of an `<a>` tag. Download progress *can* be checked using something like `fetch()` or an `XMLHttpRequest()`, though I suspect those two methods won't suffice for what you are trying to achieve in your specific case.

Comment: It can be done using an extension: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads Maybe you can convince your users to install a browser extension to support this. But, apparently, just in a webpage, no you can't